# Windows boot up process explorer like logging?

Tags: windows, performance, boot, performance-monitoring

How can one create a automatic log of applications / memory usage / cpu usages during windows boot time? Everyone hates when a machine takes 10 minutes to boot up, but it can be difficult to troubleshoot especially if the machine is largely unresponsive the entire time. Is there a way to either automate logging of perfmon type monitors or log process explorer measurements or something equivalent to help discover who the main culprits are in a really slow boot? Obviously the logger would need to have a high enough priority not to be pushed out of service by other applications during the bootup, and would have to be started early enough in the process to catch the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Windows SysInternal's [**"Process Monitor"**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will help you with that (It's advertised as having a "Boot time logging" feature). Another way would be to choose the "Boot logging" option in Windows's boot menu (Windows 7, Vista and XP) by pressing F8 when windows boots up.

Comment: Sounded like a great idea, but of the 17 minutes the machine is taking too boot to a useable state, only the final two minutes are captured by the boot logging in processor monitor. The machine at one point in the past booted in 5 minutes so that last two isn't where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I later realized Xperf might work if it can be gauranteed to start early enough.